# Return ID with INSERT INTO (conn.Execute)

Tags: .net, sql-server, sqlconnection

I'm inserting a new value using:

```
var message = conn.Execute("INSERT INTO [Message] (SenderId, Text, Date) values (@passeiDiretoUserId, @text, @date) SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()",
                new { @id, @text = send.Text, @date });
```

The query is working fine, but I need the ID of the value that was just created.
Thanks!

Comment: Look at `.ExecuteScalar` to return a single selected value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in
>   the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are
>   ignored.